# How to test background location updates iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have an app that requires the location of the user in the background to trigger certain events and notifications, similar to life360; if the user terminates the app, background location updates should still occur.

My plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

I have configured my CLLocationManager like so after receiving "Always" location permission:

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate  = self
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone  //meters
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
locationManager.startMonitoringVisits()
```

And I have setup the willFinishLaunching function like this to test if my app is summoned upon location change:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    if launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
        // App launched from the background due to location change
        UserDefaults.standard.set("Background Update Received", forKey: "locationUpdate")  
    }
    

    return true
    
}
```

The past few hours I have been driving around my city with my app terminated trying to trigger the location update but it has never happened. My iPhone has background app refresh on, and "always" location permission. I have seen the process to be tedious and immensely time consuming.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to test this than driving around all day wasting gas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the location manually in the simulator?

Comment: @LudovicoVerniani yes, still no updates received. I don't think changing he location in the simulator triggers background location updates.

Comment: If you have terminated the app (swiped up from app switcher) then you will not receive location updates; your app is terminated by the user. You can try activating significant location updates, I believe that will relaunch your app

Comment: @Paulw11 if you look closely, that’s exactly what I do already.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am simply setting a user default value to check if the app was even summoned in the first place, which it isn’t. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background Of course the app can be summoned even after it is terminated, I just can’t get it to work. Any ideas?